# Recording activities - case or contact summary page?

Tags: activities

Is it better practice to record activities in the case rather than on the contact summary?  If so, why?

Comment: Hi Kate. You may like to know that I'm currently working on a new feature for CiviCRM that would enable you to see Case Activities on the normal Contact Activities listing. This way you can use Case Activities, but not lose the benefits of being able to see all of someone's activities in one place. You can [read more](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/16360) - it's not something that's ready yet, though, but hopefully in a future release of CiviCRM.

Answer (score 2):

Kate, Welcome to CiviCRM stack exchange. About your question, it depends upon your business logic. If you want the activity to be part of the case than you should create them inside a case since the New Activity form from the Contact summary page doesn't provide ability to add activity to case. You can but obvious move the activity later after creating by using Move to case link or Move to case from task action.

If you don't want activity to be part of the case than you should use option from Contact Summary screen.

Thanks

Pradeep

Answer (score 2):

If the activity relates to the Case, then create it there but otherwise just on the Contact.

For example, if you have a case for managing volunteer onboarding, then a meeting relating to onboarding would be a case activity but a phone call about a donation would be a simple contact activity.